# Build website with angularjs 2

Tags: angular

I currently use Angularjs for my website. Now I would try to upgrade to angularjs 2 and typescript but I notice that I've to upload a lot of library (all the folder of node_modules), so is very heavy the job! Is wirght or there are other solutions?

UPGRADE

Ok, i see that to use angular2 into website I've to use webpack. So I use quickstart example of webpack and succesfully work on local machine, but when I upload to server remote doesent work!
This is my folder project structure:

```
node_modules
src
---app
---public
---style
```

So I've to upload only src folder?

Comment: What do you mean with "upload"?. Before you deploy, you build, and build produces an output directory with a few files. Not sure if this is what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upload all of the node_modules of angular 1.0.

To upgrade an Angular 1.0 app in Angular 2.0 check out this link..

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

Use webpack to bundle the scripts, there is a sample on the angular 2 's website https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I proceed with webpack example, and start with npm start, so I test my website in local, but when I upload on remote server doesnt work!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upload all your development code to the server. Webpack/brocolli will build your development code and copy it to the "dist" folder every time you change the files. You just need to copy the code from dist folder to any server.

To build the code, type ng build -prod/ ng serve -prod, it is going to check all possible error, warning that you have in project by default.

I would recommend to use angular cli, if not using, it will set up all default configuration to start up with angular js 2 default

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli